# Which frame work will be faster in page rendering.?

Tags: jstl, aem, sightly

I can see there are multiple ways of coding in **AEM, JSP, EXT JS, JSTL, Sightly, CORAL UI**. Am confused with what are the combinations that can be best to implement in AEM for a faster web page rendering to the end user.?

Comment: Adobe is only supporting Sightly from 6.1 onwards. All other platforms will work as long as they don't break due to external factors but no new features will be added to non-Sightly platforms in future. So, based on this info, not sure if you even have a choice. Technically, the page rendition speed depends on HTML organisation so not sure which aspect of speed you are talking about (server side compilation of scripts or client side HTML rendition).

Comment: As other commenters already said: You are mixing up a lot of things. There are basically just two "frameworks" you can choose from: JSP and HTL (former Sightly). And since HTL is the only _real_ option from AEM 6.1 onwards you do not even have this choice. But even if you could choose, it does not really matter, since you should try to deliver your pages from cache anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rendering speed is not relevant as the content is delivered from a caching layer. For cache warmups the architecture is crucial, not the technology.

Answer (score 1):

First you are mixing front-end and back-end rendering engines. Second ExtJS and Coral UI are mostly used for authoring and not at render time in publish instances. as i.net said not sure which aspect of performance you are talking about but here is what Adobe said when Sightly was released:

- Use Sightly on parts that are not hit very often and JSP on parts of the pages that are hit often by your viewers, that being said, both JSP and HTL (Sightly) are compiled by AEM to Bytecode, so not sure how relevant this is now. We decided to go full Sightly at rendering because it makes our life easier (FE and BE), as for speed there are so many layers of caching available that it's not much of a concern.

I hope that this helps.